# Can I add fonts to Google Chrome?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I was playing around with some settings on google chrome and realized you could set default fonts / sizes. I wanted to set my monospace font to "Roboto Mono", which I have installed through SkyFonts.

When I go to the [Chrome font settings](http://chrome://settings/fonts), I do not see an option to add fonts. It just has a preloaded list.

For the record, I've tried searching on superuser and on google. The only articles that seem to come up are "here is how to change your font" or "here is how to add a font to chrome os" - neither of which answer my question: **Can I add other fonts to Google Chrome?**

Comment: Chrome is automatically able to use all installed fonts. How exactly do you want to add it? Change the defaults?

Comment: @DanielB Turns out I'm stupid. Basically, in order for it to work correctly, you have to run SkyFonts, and then relaunch chrome. (I was just like...reloading the page, expecting it to work)

Comment: @Awesomolocity You aren't stupid. Chrome is stupid. It used to be possible to activate a font and add a `font-family: 'My Activated Font';` CSS rule and have it work immediately. Front-end designers could try out a bunch of fonts directly working in hot-reload. They broke functionality and won't fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since posting this, and the answer to the question was posted in the comments. But those can be easy to miss so I figured I'd highlight it as an actual answer.

> Basically, in order for it to work correctly, you have to run SkyFonts, and **then relaunch chrome**. (I was just like...reloading the page, expecting it to work)

For some strange, unknown reasons, you need to fully relaunch chrome for any new fonts to be able to be used.